# Memory leaks about the Activity

Tags: android, memory-leaks

In the open source library:android-async-http , Has a method cancelRequests(context, boolean):

```
public void cancelRequests(final Context context, final boolean mayInterruptIfRunning) {
    if (context == null) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Passed null Context to cancelRequests");
        return;
    }
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            List<RequestHandle> requestList = requestMap.get(context);
            if (requestList != null) {
                for (RequestHandle requestHandle : requestList) {
                    requestHandle.cancel(mayInterruptIfRunning);
                }
                requestMap.remove(context);
            }
        }
    };
    if (Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()) {
        new Thread(r).start();
    } else {
        r.run();
    }
}
```

The `cancelRequests` function will be called as following.

```
class TestActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        cancelRequests(this, true);
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

This is a memory leak? How to solve?

Comment: Can you please clarify your question?

Comment: Instead pass the activity's `context` to `cancelRequests`, you can pass the application context `getApplicationContext()` to the function call to avoid activity memory leak.

Comment: But I need to the Context to get the List<RequestHandle> , 

List<RequestHandle> requestList = requestMap.get(context);

Answer (score 0):

> An Async Task will not be canceled or destroyed at the moment the
>   activity is dismissed

Dont call stop Async like

> cancelRequests(this, true);

Let system decide it. You only pause and stop it by the check value, or stop permantly. It's real algorithm

Comment: How to make the async task associated with the Activity of the life cycle ?